# Translating query MySQL Lead Partition By Over

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that works in MySQL 8.0 that I'm struggling to translate to MySQL 5.7

```
UPDATE (SELECT se.*,
        CASE WHEN se.end_date IS NULL 
             THEN dateadd(DAY, 0, LEAD(se.start_date, 1)
                                  OVER(PARTITION BY se.id ORDER BY se.start_date))
             ELSE se.end_date END AS newEndDate
        FROM `better`.`DimUserTemp` AS se
        WHERE se.id IN (SELECT id FROM `better`.user_update_staging))
SET end_date = newEndDate
WHERE end_date IS NULL;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What does the data look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery to calculate the next start date and then use this in the `update` . . . assuming you have a primary key in the table:

```
update dut
    from better.DimUserTemp dut join
         (select dut.*,
                 (select min(dut3.startdate)
                  from better.DimUserTemp dut3
                  where dut3.id = dut2.id and
                        dut3.startdate > dut2.startdate
                 ) as next_startdate
          from better.DimUserTemp dut2
          where dut2.id in (select uus.id from better.user_update_staging uus)
         ) dut2
         on dut2.id = dut.id  -- or whatever the pk is
    set dut.end_date = dut2.next_start_date
    where dut.end_date is null;
```